# how do i find the variance of an estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, parameter-estimation

If the Estimator was simply the sample mean $s=\frac{\sum{x}}{n}$ taken from a binomial distribution (a random example) how would i calculate the variance of this? I am trying to use the difference between the expectations squared but im not sure what the expectation of the infinite sum would be.

Comment: Well. just tha $Var(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2$ so you just have to expand the square of a finite many terms (that is because you have finite aleatorium measure $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and then use that the samples are independient from each other for the product terms. Now your random variable $X=\frac{\sum_i=1^n x_i}{n}$...

Comment: you mean that because the expectation of the sum is the sum of the expecations? okay thanks, then the expectation of each term for this case would simply be the mean for the binomial distribution once I have expanded it so np? just to check if my logic is correct.

Comment: It is always true that the expectation has this property. But the random variable $X^2$ is a little bit more delicated, you have to apply the multinomial $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^2$ in order to obtain terms $x_i^2$ and double products $2x_i x_j$ and see what happens if the sample has the values independent from each other.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a random sample from a population with mean $\mu$ and
variance $\sigma^2,$  let $T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$

Then

$$E(T) = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = n\mu.$$

Also, elements of a random sample are independent, so we have

$$V(T) = V\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n V(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2 = n\sigma^2.$$

Also, with $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \frac{1}{n}T,$
so that

$$E(\bar X) = E\left(\frac{1}{n}T\right) = \frac{1}{n}E(T) = \frac{1}{n}n\mu = \mu.$$

Thus. the expected value of the sample mean $\bar X$ is the population mean $\mu.$ (We say that $\bar X$ is an *unbiased* estimator of $\mu.)$

Moreover,

$$V(\bar X) = V\left(\frac{1}{n}T\right) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2V(T) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2n\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2 = \sigma^2/n.$$

*Notes:* (1) In the first displayed equation the expected value of a sum of random variables is the sum of the expected values, whether nor not the random variables are independent.

(2) However, the variance of the sum of random variables is *not* necessarily equal to the sum of the variances, unless the random variables are *independent.*

[As a trivial case, if all $n \ge 2$ of the $X_i = X,$ then the $X_i$ are not independent
and we have $V\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = V(nX) = n^2V(X) \ne nV(X).$ As another example, if $X_1 = -X_2$ with $V(X_1)=V(X_2) > 0,$ then $V(X_1+X_2) = V(0) = 0 \ne V(X_1)+V(X_2).]$

(3) For the standard deviation of the mean of a random sample, we can take square roots to get, $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ (Sometimes this is called the
'standard error' of $\bar X.)$